# Jira JQL style search in MVC.net

Tags: library, mvc

I need to replicate the Jira JQL style advanced search in my .Net MVC project with EF.

"What is JQL style advanced search?" http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/01/jql-the-most-flexible-way-to-search-jira-14/

I've got some ideas on how I could build this from scratch but am really hoping someone knows of an existing library/package that I can use instead.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find any answer to this question or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155203/i-need-jql-for-mvc-net-any-ideas)?

Comment: no not yet. As this is on the "nice to have" list of my current project. If I get time to build it I will share with all and sundry.